# Unable to set live wallpaper in iOS 10

Tags: ios

On iOS 10, when you go to select a wallpaper, you can select live photos. Then on the preview screen, there is a segmented control that allows you to choose from:

- still
- perspective
- live

However, "still" is preselected and I can't tap on perspective or live. Tapping on the segmented control animates the live photo but it doesn't select what you are tapping. I have an iPhone 7 running iOS 10.0.3.

Is this due to some other setting or is it a really nasty bug? Force-quitting settings didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you by any chance have Low Power Mode on?

[image]

> Dynamic wallpaper and Perspective Zoom are disabled when Low Power Mode is on.

Go to Settings > Battery and disable Low Power  Mode to be able to select a Live Wallpaper and use the Live Photo or Perspective settings.